# What is the relationship between slices and references in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, reference, slice

I am completely new to Rust (as in I just started looking at it yesterday), and am working my way through "The Rust Programming Language". I'm a little stuck on Chapters 4.2 (References and Borrowing) / 4.3 (The Slice Type) and am trying to solidify my initial understanding of references before I move on. I'm an experienced programmer whose background is mainly in C++ (I am intimately familiar with several languages, but C++ is what I'm most comfortable with).

Consider the following Rust code:

```
let string_obj: String = String::from("My String");
let string_ref: &String = &string_obj;
let string_slice: &str = &string_obj[1..=5];
```

Based on my understanding, from the first line, `string_obj` is an object of type `String` that is stored on the stack, which contains three fields: (1) a pointer to the text "My String", allocated on the heap, encoded in UTF-8; (2) A length field with value 9; (3) A capacity field with a value >= 9. That's straightforward enough.

From the second line, `string_ref` is an immutable reference to a `String` object, also stored on the stack, which contains a single field - a pointer to `string_obj`. This leads me to believe that (leaving aside ownership rules, semantics, and other things I am yet to learn about references), a reference is essentially a pointer to some other object. Again, pretty straightforward.

It's the third line which causing me some headaches. From the documentation, it would appear that `string_slice` is an object of type `&str` that is stored on the stack, and contains two fields: 1)  a pointer to the text "y Str", within the text "My String" associated with `string_obj`. 2) A length field with value 5.

But, by appearances at least, the `&str` type is by definition an immutable reference to an object of type `str`. So my questions are as follows:

1. What exactly *is* an `str`, and how is it represented in memory?
2. How does `&str` - a *reference* type, which I *thought* was simply a pointer - contain TWO fields (a pointer AND a length)?
3. How does Rust know in general what / how many fields to create when constructing a reference? (and consequently how does the programmer know?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slices are *primitive types* in Rust, which means that they don't necessarily have to follow the syntax rules of other types.  In this case, `str` and `&str` are special and are treated with a bit of magic.

The type `str` doesn't *really* exist, since you can't have a slice that owns its contents.  The reason for requiring us to spell this type "`&str`" is syntactic: the `&` reminds us that we're working with data borrowed from somewhere else, *and* it's required to be able to specify lifetimes, such as:

```
fn example<'a>(x: &String, y: &'a String) -> &'a str {
    &y[..]
}
```

It's also necessary so that we can differentiate between an immutably-borrowed string slice (`&str`) and a mutably-borrowed string slice (`&mut str`). (Though the latter are somewhat limited in their usefulness and so you don't see them that often.)

Note that the same thing applies to array slices.  We have arrays like `[u8; 16]` and we have slices like `&[u8]` but we don't really directly interact with `[u8]`.  Here the mutable variant (`&mut [u8]`) is more useful than with string slices.

> What exactly *is* an `str`, and how is it represented in memory?

As per above, `str` kind-of doesn't really exist by itself.  The layout of `&str` though is as you suspect -- a pointer and a length.

(`str` is the actual characters referred to by the slice, and is a so-called [dynamically-sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html).  In the general case, a `&T` can't exist without a `T` to refer to.  In this case it's a bit backwards in that the `str` doesn't exist without the `&str` slice.)

> How does `&str` - a *reference* type, which I *thought* was simply a pointer - contain TWO fields (a pointer AND a length)?

As a primitive, it's a special case handled by the compiler.

> How does Rust know in general what / how many fields to create when constructing a reference? (and consequently how does the programmer know?)

If it's a non-slice reference, then it's either a pointer or it's nothing (if the reference itself can be optimized away).